# Strange form submit bug?

Tags: php, html, laravel

HTML:

```
<div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_1" name="pin_selection_1" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div><div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_2" name="pin_selection_2" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div><div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_3" name="pin_selection_3" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div><div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_4" name="pin_selection_4" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div><div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_5" name="pin_selection_5" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div><div class="select is-pulled-right" style="margin-top:-8px;"> <select id="pin_selection_6" name="pin_selection_6" class="is-pulled-right"> <option value="0"> 0 </option> <option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option> <option value="3"> 3 </option> <option value="4"> 4 </option> <option value="5"> 5 </option> <option value="6"> 6 </option> <option value="7"> 7 </option> <option value="8"> 8 </option> <option value="9"> 9 </option> </select> </div>
```

PHP:

```
if ($request->input('pin_severity') != 'disabled') {
    $user->pin_code = 
    $request->input('pin_selection_6') . 
    $request->input('pin_selection_5') . 
    $request->input('pin_selection_4') . 
    $request->input('pin_selection_3') . 
    $request->input('pin_selection_2') . 
    $request->input('pin_selection_1');
}

$user->save();

echo 'pin_selection_1: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_6') . '<br>';
echo 'pin_selection_2: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_5') . '<br>';
echo 'pin_selection_3: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_4') . '<br>';
echo 'pin_selection_4: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_3') . '<br>';
echo 'pin_selection_5: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_2') . '<br>';
echo 'pin_selection_6: ' . $request->input('pin_selection_1') . '<br>';
exit();
```

I use 6 different select dropdowns to pick a 6 digit pin code, when saving it using the PHP code I am receiving some issues. My database column is an int with length 6 NOT NULL.

When saving the pin as something like `123456` or `223344` it works perfectly and saves correctly. Earlier I tried doing something more complicated, `020304`

It went through, but saved in the database as `20304`, the strange thing is, my echo displayed it exactly as I entered it, but it saved in the database incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your echos are displayed correctly because they act as strings.

But when you save the pin in your database, Laravel/mysql converts the string to an integer, hence, the mismatch.

If you want it to be inserted as is, change the datatype of your `pin_code` column to varchar